# importing a .java class into netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am new to java and i'm unsure if i am doing something wrong however here is the scenario. I have designed a simple GUI in netbeans 7.01 and i am trying to import class A (which contains A.java and A.form) into netbeans 7.1.1. The problem is, when i do the import, my file looks empty? its as if there was no code written and its default blank. why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below steps instead:

1. copy class A (which contains A.java and A.form).
2. Right click on any package of your project folder that you would like to import.
3. Select the paste option.

It should work.